# can I use logical operators to remove all files that matches with one and/or other pattern in a single line?

Tags: shell, command-line, wildcards

I want to remove `.txt` or `.csv` files in a single line.

What I have in my directory

```
tachomi$ ls
file1.csv  file1.sql  file1.txt  file2.csv  file2.sql  file2.txt
```

I only want `.sql` files so I want to know if there's a way to execute commands using logical operators such as `AND` or  `OR` in a single line

```
tachomi$ rm *.txt AND *.csv
tachomi$ rm *.txt OR *.csv
```

How to remove all files that match with two given patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
rm *.txt *.csv
```

And if your shell supports brace expansion, you can:

```
rm *.{txt,csv}
```

Comment: oh, so with a single space between each pattern is done, but... logical operators are not supported in a single command line?

Comment: @tachomi some *shells* support logical operators as an extension of their *filename glob* functionality: for example `@(*.csv|*.txt)` in bash. However you don't need that simply to delete files with both extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Simply list both patterns if you want to match files that match either pattern, that is, files that match `*.txt` and files that match `*.csv`, or in other words, files that match `*.txt` or `*.csv`. (The nesting of quantifiers and logical operators matters!)

```
rm *.txt *.csv
```

Note that if either pattern does not match any file, it will be left intact, so `rm` will complain that it can't find a file called `*.txt` or `*.csv`. A common way of avoiding a complaint is to use `rm -f`, which silently ignores non-existent files.

```
rm -f *.txt *.csv
```

There is no operator to match strings that match both pattern 1 and pattern 2. In this case, there is no string that matches both `*.txt` and `*.csv` anyway.

In ksh, the pattern `@(*.txt|*.csv)` or `*.@(txt|csv)` matches strings that match either `*.txt` or `*.csv`. You can use this pattern in bash if you run `shopt -s extglob` first; you can use it in zsh if you run `setopt ksh_glob` first, or you can use zsh's native syntax `*.(txt|csv)`. Note that if there is no file matching the compound pattern, it will be passed to the command as is. In ATT ksh (and only in ATT ksh, not in mksh, bash or zsh), you can use `~(N)*.@(txt|csv)` to expand to an empty list if no file matches the pattern. You would still need to use `rm -f` so that there is no complaint about a missing argument.

```
rm -f ~(N)*.@(txt|csv)
```

In bash, run `shopt -s nullglob` first to make all patterns expand to the empty list if they match nothing.

```
shopt -s nullglob extglob; rm -f *.@(txt|csv)
```

In zsh, use the `N` glob qualifier, or run `setopt nullglob` first.

```
rm -f *.(txt|csv)(N)
setopt nullglob extglob; rm -f *.@(txt|csv)
```